# Gene representation for production planning with constraints

Tags: genetic-algorithm, planning

I'm trying to improve the throughput of a production system. The exact type of the system isn't relevant (I think).

### Description

1. The system consists of a **LINE** of stations (numbered 1, 2, 3...) and an **ARM**.
2. The system receives an **ITEM** at random times.
3. Each **ITEM** has a **PLAN** associated with it (for example, **ITEM1** may have a **PLAN** which
   says it needs to go through station 3, then 1, then 5). The **PLAN** includes timing information on
   how long the **ITEM** would be at each station (a range of hard max/min values).
4. Every **STATION** can hold one **ITEM** at a time.
5. The **ARM** is used to move each **ITEM** from one **STATION** to the next. Each **PLAN** includes
   timing information for the **ARM** as well, which is a fixed value.

### Current Practice

I have two current (working) planning solutions.

The first maintains a master list of usage for each **STATION**, consider this a 'booking' approach.
As each new **ITEM-N** enters, the system searches ahead to find the earliest possible slot where
**PLAN-N** would fit. So for example, it would try to fit it at t=0, then progressively try higher
delays till it found a fit (well actually I have some heuristics here to cut down processing time,
but the approach holds)

The second maintains a list for each **ITEM** specifying when it is to start. When a new **ITEM-N**
enters, the system compares its' **PLAN-N** with all existing lists to find a suitable time to
start. Again, it starts at t=0 then progressively tries higher delays.

Neither of the two solutions take advantage of the range of times an **ITEM** is allowed at each
station. A fixed time is assumed (midpoint or minimum).

### Ideal Solution

It's quite self-evident that there exists situations where an incoming **ITEM** would be able to
start earlier than otherwise possible if some of the current **ITEM**s change the duration they
spend in certain **STATION**, whether by shortening that duration (so the new **ITEM** could enter
the **STATION** instead) or lengthening that duration (so the **ARM** has time to move the
**ITEM**).

I'm trying to implement a Genetic Algorithm solution to the problem. My current gene contains N
numbers (between 0 and 1) where N is the total number of stations among all item currently in the
system as well as a new item which is to be added in. It's trivial to convert this gene to an
actual duration (0 would be the min duration, 1 would be the max, scale linearly in between).

However, this gene representation consistently produces un-usable plans which overlap with each
other. The reason for this is that when multiple items are already arranged ideally (consecutive in
time, planning wise), no variation on durations is possible. This is unavoidable because once items
are already being processed, they cannot be delayed or brought forward.

An example of the above situation, say **ITEMA** is in **STATION3** for durations t1 to t2 and t3 to
t4. **ITEMB** then comes along and occupies **STATION3** for duration t2 to t3 (so **STATION3** is fully
utilized between t1 and t4). With my current gene representation, I'm virtually guaranteed never to
find a valid solution, since that would require certain elements of the gene to have exactly the
correct value so as not to generate an overlap.

### Questions

1. Is there a better gene representation than I describe above?
2. Would I be better served doing some simple hill-climbing to find modifiable timings? Or, is GA
   actually suited to this problem?